# Sending a Report NG report via email

Tags: testng, reportng

While doing the selenium automation using testNg & report NG.Reports are generated  on execution. 
[Surefire reports[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apZNW.png)
Then I have implement the send email the  to send the index.html file.But what I have observed that the index.html missing the require js & css file. How to send the CSS & js file with the html file to view the index.html file properly.
I have used the maven postman plugin to send the mail.
The requirement is on click of the attached html file should display with the data.

Comment: when mailing with index.html, also attach those two ..is it not possible in ur case?

Comment: By attaching also it is not working. We have to zip the folder and send it.

Answer (score 0):

Surefire generates a **emailablereport.html**  file that you can send which I dont think needs a CSS to go with it.    Personally, I generate reports using Extent reports and i send HTML links in the emails.